# Failing to use String.Format to display Version String in WPF

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf

I am a C++ developer and recently shifted to C#. I am working on a wpf app where I need to work on `String.Format`. In My C++ application, I had used `sprintf` to obtain the result but when it comes to C#, string.format helped me achieve it. Now I have come across a tricky situation where I need to achieve the similar thing but with different values. Here Is the C++ code:

```
char t_str[4] = {};
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{ 
    sprintf(t_str, "%02X", buffer[i]);
m_apiResponse[i]->setText(String(t_str));
}
```

where `buffer[0] = 20;
                buffer[1] = 30;
                buffer[2] = 40;
                buffer[3] = 50;` and `m_apiResponse` is a textbox.

Even though `string.format` was also helpful, I rather choose the easiset way of doing it. I had done this in my C# as follows:

```
Response1Box = buffer[0].ToString("X2");
Response2Box = buffer[1].ToString("X2");
Response3Box = buffer[2].ToString("X2");
Response4Box = buffer[3].ToString("X2");
```

It worked well and gave me the answer i wanted. But now I have come across a twisted version of it in my c++ app..... Here is the code:

```
unsigned char buffer[8] = {};
char verString[64] = {};

m_msp430->WriteInternalCommand(cmd, 1, buffer);
m_msp430->ReadInternalCommand(cmd, 4, buffer);

sprintf(verString, "FPGA 0x42 Version (dd/mm/yyyy ID): %02d/%02d/20%02d %02d", ((buffer[3] & 0xF8) >> 3), 
            (buffer[2] & 0x0F), ((buffer[2] & 0xF0) >> 4), (buffer[3] & 0x07));

m_versionString->setText(String(verString), false);
```

Here m_versionString is a label and once this statement is executed, it prints e.g. `FPGA 0x42 Version (dd/mm/yyyy ID): 00/00/2012 23`. I tried it in C# as follows:

```
// Description of VersionString label which displays
    private string _VersionString;
    public string VersionString
    {
        get
        {
            return _VersionString;
        }

        set
        {
            _VersionString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("VersionString");
        }
    }

    public void GetVersion()
    {
        int cmd = 0x0A42;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[8];
        Byte[] verString = new Byte[64];

        mComm.WriteInternalCommand(cmd, 1, ref buffer);
        mComm.ReadInternalCommand(cmd, 4, ref buffer);            

        // Failing to figure out how to achieve it

        VersionString = Convert.ToString(verString);
    }
```

How can i perform these operations and display it on my VersionString?? :) Please help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C++ code is not equivalent to your C# code. You are masking and bit shifting each byte before your sprintf. There's no way that C# would know how to mask off the individual bytes to make your string.

Not much time right now.. but basically something like this..

```
verString = String.Format("FPGA 0x42 Version (dd/mm/yyyy ID): {0}/{1}/20{2} {3}", ((buffer[3] & 0xF8) >> 3), 
        (buffer[2] & 0x0F), ((buffer[2] & 0xF0) >> 4), (buffer[3] & 0x07));
```

or you can do it byte by byte without String.Format before calling convert

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes you are right. Is their any alternate way where masking of the individual bits can be done and result must be achieved the way C++ code does? :)

Comment: why don't you like String.format? I think it is closest to sprintf as you have, I 'll see in a min when I have some time ;-)